# Measure and category of codes of countable ordinals

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

A well-known result from descriptive set theory says that for any countable ordinal $\alpha$, the set of reals that code a well-ordering on $\omega$ with ordertype $\alpha$ is a Borel set. I wonder if such sets have positive measure or are non-meager.

An observation that might be useful: given a well-ordering $R\subseteq (\omega\times\omega)$ which has ordertype $\alpha$, any permutation of $\omega$ will generate an isomorphic relation. So the cardinality of the set of codes of $\alpha$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$. But I am not sure how to use this fact.

Comment: The details of your coding mechanism matter a lot here. For example, the set of non-transitive relations on $\omega$ is comeager and of full measure under the usual approach, so the set of reals that code any linear order in the first place is null and meager a fortiori. Meanwhile, every sufficiently generic linear order is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, so I can't imagine a sense in which the set of codes of ordinals is nonmeager (and an analogous if trickier result will hold for measure).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Hmm, I had in mind the approach of checking if $2^m\times 3^n$ gets sent to $0$ or $1$. Is this the usual approach? In any case, I mistakenly assumed that coding details don't matter. I also don't see how codes for non-transitive relations form a comeager and measure one set. Could you please elaborate a little? Thank you!

Comment: Almost all reals $x$ (in the sense  of measure and in the sense of Baire category) have the property that the ordinals recursive in $x$ are only the recursive ordinals. So any coding scheme that gives some non-recursive ordinal a positive-measure or non-meager set of codes would have to be a non-recursive (in fact not even hyperarithmetic) scheme.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Nice mosquito-blaster. :P

Comment: @ikrto For comeagerness, note that any finite partial relation on $\omega$ can always be extended to a finite partial *non-transitive* relation on $\omega$; this means that the set of reals coding non-transitive binary relations (in any of the usual ways, anyways) is dense open, so a fortiori comeager. (The intuition I give [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381314/381504#381504) may also be useful.) Measure is a bit more slippery, but note that all we need to violate transitivity is to see a single forbidden three-point configuration appear.